# Can't Set Origin

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created a slider menu that modifies the origin of all my views. I can't seem to force one of my `UIButtons` to display the animated content it displays in the center. (It wants to display/anchor in the top left corner where my slider menu button is) Does anybody have any suggestions?

I have a feeling that `initWithPoint:_shareButton.center` might be the key

```
-(IBAction)shareTapped:(id)sender
 {
      if(shareBubbles) {
            shareBubbles = nil;
        }

      shareBubbles.center = CGPointMake(150, 150); // set center
      //center = frame.origin + bounds.size / 2
      // CGPoint shareButton = CGPointMake(78, 382);

      shareBubbles = [[AAShareBubbles alloc] initWithPoint:_shareButton.center radius:radius  inView:self.view];
      //shareBubbles.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(200, -100);

      _shareButton.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(100,-100);
      _shareButton.center = CGPointMake(300, -300);
      // shareBubbles.center = CGPointMake(200, -200);
      // _shareButton.origin = CGPointMake (0.0,0.0);
```

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout?

Comment: No, turned it on but it didn't seem to affect any change at all